# Find all substrings in a string using recursion Python 3

Tags: python, recursion

How would you make a list of all the possible substrings in a string using recursion? (no loops) I know that you can recurse using s[1:] to cut off the first position and s[:-1] to cut off the last position. So far I have come up with this:

```
def lst_substrings(s):
  lst = []
  if s == "":
    return lst
  else:
    lst.append(s)
    return lst_substrings(s[1:])
```

but this would only make a list of all the substrings that are sliced by the first position if it worked

Comment: what you want to do is not very clear...what do you want to do ? have you any example ?

Comment: hint: recursion frequently takes what you have in the current call (`lst`) and combines it with a recursive call that uses less of the initial input (`lst_substrings(s[1:])`).  In this case, you seem to be missing the part where you combine what you have in the current call with the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Actually that will only ever return an empty list; perhaps you should debug it and try to understand what *currently* happens before attempting to add more functionality.

Answer (score -2):

Fun problem, here's my solution - feedback appreciated.

### Output

```
In [73]: lstSubStrings("Hey")
Out[73]: ['', 'y', 'H', 'Hey', 'He', 'e', 'ey']
```

### Solution

```
def lstSubStrings(s):
    # BASE CASE: when s is empty return the empty string
    if(len(s) is 0):
        return [s]
    substrs = []
    # a string is a substring of itself - by the definition of subset in math
    substrs.append(s)
    # extend the list of substrings by all substrings with the first
    # character cut out
    substrs.extend(lstSubStrings(s[1:]))
    # extend the list of substrings by all substrings with the last 
    # character cut out
    substrs.extend(lstSubStrings(s[:-1]))
    # convert the list to `set`, removing all duplicates, and convert 
    # back to a list
    substrs = list(set(substrs))

    return substrs
```

Comment: for a string as "apbple" your function never outputs apple as you only cut at the beginning or at the end

Comment: @Soyol "apple" is not a *substring* of "apbple". It is a *subsequence* however. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Duh. Just realized now that practically the same solution has been posted by someone who was quicker than me. Vote for his answer. I'll leave this as it is a bit more concise and in case you want to sort the resulting list by substring length. Use len(item, item), i.e. leave the - sign, to sort in ascending order.

This will do:

```
def lst_substrings(s):
    lst = [s]
    if len(s) > 0:
        lst.extend(lst_substrings(s[1:]))
        lst.extend(lst_substrings(s[:-1]))
    return list(set(lst))

sub = lst_substrings("boby")
sub.sort(key=lambda item: (-len(item), item))
print(sub)
```

Output is:

```
['boby', 'bob', 'oby', 'bo', 'by', 'ob', 'b', 'o', 'y', '']
```